# Microsoft equivalent of Spring Batch

Tags: architecture, spring-batch

We are designing an architecture that requires a batch framework.

On the Java side we are considering [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/).

We are wondering what are the equivalent tools / frameworks in the Microsoft stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no ETL frameworks developed by Microsoft; there exist some non-MS ones:

- http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/16/Rhino-ETL-2.0.aspx
- http://www.csvreader.com/

And probably some others which I don't know of. Of course these two don't really compare to Spring Batch. +1 to Sean's question, are you sure you need pure MS-based solution?

Comment: There is an open source .Net Batch Framework based upon the Spring Batch specification ( JSR 352 ) that is available on nugget and Github :

https://github.com/SummerBatch

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SummerBatch/

Answer (score 8):

The Question is: do you need a Microsoft-based solution?

Spring Batch should integrate nicely, even in a Microsoft world. It can run on Microsoft servers, access Microsoft databases, use Microsoft protocols (or rather: use the same standard protocols that Microsoft products use).

If you need to integrate it with actual .net code, you can easily do that through a number of WebService protocols.

Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

For a complete batch framework, beyond the batch programming model that Spring Batch provides, have a look at **Websphere XD Compute Grid**.

I recommend you to read this thread in DeveloperWorks http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14298983 *Comparing Spring Batch to WebSphere XD Compute Grid*.

Also, this thread in TheServerSide http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=47506#242521 *Article: Spring Batch Overview* is interesting to read. It positions Spring Batch beside Websphere XD and other frameworks like Quartz and Flux.

Comment: Both of these are ancient and outdated. Spring Batch has changed a lot over the last years. I'm not saying it would "win" now, but I'd be interested in an updated comparison with Spring Batch 2.x