# Is there a SPRING batch equivalent in .NET

Tags: .net, spring-batch, batch-processing

I came across Spring BATCH and it seems to be a fully fledged batch library. I however was not able to find any .NET equivalent library. There is Summer Batch but it does not seem to be kept up to date.

Have any of you come across any other libraries. Alternatively, what do you .NET folks use to create batch data processing applications.

The use case here is data ingestion -> merging, splitting, validations -> data export as a file. It is not a big data use case and there are not more than 10 million rows in a flat file.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to an already-closed question [Microsoft equivalent of Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908184/microsoft-equivalent-of-spring-batch).

I came across an open source framework, [Summer Batch](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/SummerBatchCore) that is inspired by [JSR-352](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352). It seems to be well-maintained as well.

I have not used it yet. But hoping to try it out sometime.

Comment: Last commit to the SummerBatch repo was in 2021 and their company Blu Age was bought out by amazon to provide Mainframe Migration consultancy service for getting onto AWS. The last day noting activity by SummerBatchTeam account was 2019. I think its safe to say SummerBatch died on the vine. While it looks very promising there is a severe shortage of resources on it sadly